# Where to put the live-search-docs config file in all in one alfresco project?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have been going through some blog posts that tell how to customize the live search . What is not clear to me is where should I place the live-search-docs.get.config.xml file in my all-in-one-share project so that it is bootstrapped and deployed in the correct location.

Please can some one advise where the file should be placed in my all-in-one alfresco project?

From the link below

https://www.bluefishgroup.com/insights/ecm/adding-metadata-fields-to-simple-search-and-live-search-with-alfresco-5/

they suggest the search query customization file to be placed under

> These files can now be modified to add additional metadata fields as
>   needed. Once the files have been updated, they should be deployed to
>   the ‘extensions’ directory so that they will override the out of the
>   box configuration. If you are deploying your code as a custom AMP
>   file, the files should target the following directory:
>
> tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search

if my file needs to end up in the above path in my WAR, where exactly should I place the search file in my all-in-one alfresco project so that its deployed to the above folder? I would like this to be bootstrapped with my all in one project. I tried putting the file under src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts with the remaining path for the file but that did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a copy of that file in:

```
my-all-in-one-project-platform-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/
```

where, of course, my-all-in-one-project-platform-jar must be substituted with the name that you have specified when the project was created with the all-in-one archetype.

The file in the extension subpath will override the corresponding OOTB files.

See [Web scripts](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-webscripts.html)